# PL/SQL how to make current time variable?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

My block:

```
create or replace procedure currentime IS
    current_time VARCHAR2(50):=  TO_CAHR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS' ) ;

    --current_time VARCHAR2(50):=  SELECT TO_CAHR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(current_time);
end;

set serveroutput on;
call currentime();
```

PL/SQL error:

**Error(14,1): PLS-00103: "SET"**

Comment: That's a PL/SQL compilation error, but it doesn't look like it came from PL/SQL Developer (tagged in the question). What tool are you using and how are you running the code above? `set serveroutput` is from SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer running as a script. Possibly you need a `/` after the PL/SQL block (that is, on the line after `end;`) but it depends on the tool.

Comment: `TO_CARH` did you mean  `to_cHar`? Also, to better solve your problem,  what is the reason for wanting to change the time like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
create or replace procedure currentime IS
    current_time VARCHAR2(50) ;    

begin
    dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS' ));

    current_time :=  TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS' );

    dbms_output.put_line(current_time );

end;

set serveroutput on;
call currentime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `/` terminator after you are compiling the procedure. Below is an example of how your output should look after adding the terminator. I've also slightly modified the procedure to not need a variable.

#### Code

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE currentime
IS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS'));
END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CALL currentime ();
```

[image: sqlcl output]